Connecting and merging multiple RNA 3D structures in PyMol/Chimera
I have an optimized design for the corn RNA aptamer, PDB: 5BJO. I generated the 3D structures for the parts that I plan to add on trRosettaRNA. I want to connect them with the 5BJO PDB fiIe in PyMol, then perform Molecular dynamics. Is this possible?
This is the final design that I am trying to get. I have the 3D structure for each part separately. I was looking for a way to connect them together to build this model. Is it possible to assemble them in PyMol or other softwares? Thank you.


what do you mean by "Is it possible to connect and merge 4 different PDB files together," please clarify and produce an example of actual input and desidered output

@alpha do consider signing pippo1980's answer as accepted. Its good to do this all round.

@pippo1980
Thank you, I updated the description.

I see. Think you'll have to add manually the CONECT record between protein chains and RNA polymer. See Creating "stable" bond with PYMOL and the PDB file for 1ZR2:
Structure of a Synaptic gamma-delta Resolvase Tetramer Covalently Linked to two Cleaved DNAs

about pymol, when saving ALL (or ENABLED) objects in a .pdb file toghether it does keep atom numbering and remember that other Ligands (HETATM) are saved next to the chain they belong to

Pdb use ter records  this is something new to me too, try to use it before saving if you wish to create single chains out of multiple

@alpha do consider signing pippo1980's answer as accepted. Its good to do this all round and its a comprehensive answer including the points in the discussion.

in PyMol use, from menu :
File ---> Export Molecule... ---> and before hitting Save
select the molecules you want to save toghether (in the same .pdb file)
with the Selection drop down list either all (all the loaded mols are saved) or enabled (you can enable the ones you want to be saved toghether)
Examples of Save menu :


For command line see Thread: [PyMOL] independent positioning of two proteins, in preparation for RosettaDock? 

Thank you. This can save the 4 structures in one PDB file, but I wanted to first connect them together, to assemble the final structure, then save into one PDB file. Alignment is not the way to do it, as far as I understand. Is it possible in PyMol or other softwares?

what do you mean by "Is it possible to connect and merge 4 different PDB files together," please clarify and produce an example of actual input and desidered output –
pippo1980
